# Performance review for internship

Tags: internship, performance-reviews, quitting

I've been doing an internship for a large company and I have an evaluation with my boss. The company was acquired 5 years ago and most people I work with tell me how much they hate working for the company that acquired them. In a way they tell me working here is a bad job. Because the people who work here tell me this isn't a good place to work, and because I don't like the kind of work I'm doing, I really don't want to work here. I'm worried about how this may affect my evaluation because at times I find it hard to be motivated and in a sense I don't care if they think I'm doing a good job. How should I go about this? What kind of mindset should I go into the evaluation with? For example should I say something like “I do not think this job is a good fit for me” or should I just listen and say as little as possible. I've never had an evaluation like this before.

Comment: Well, do you want to work there or not?

Comment: Hi Jslam, welcome to workplace.SE.  Generally, we are unable to give you answers for questions relating to what course of action you should be taking.  It's not our place to tell you, as only YOU can fully unerstand your own situation.  I'd advise you look over our (recently redesigned...) FAQ located [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help).  In regards to your situation, it sounds like you might already have your own answer, but again it's not our place to say.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Well since it is an intership it could something the OP needs for their degree.  Second maybe they have bills and obligations that they have to pay for.  A sucky job pays far better than no job.

Comment: yea I need it for a degree and I signed a contract. And I need to make money some way. If it wouldn't mess with my school I would've quit by now.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I don't see what you're getting at. I never said I was doing a bad job. As long as I don't quit or get fired then it will meet my school requirements. If I do quit or get fired then I would have to do another internship.

Comment: Close voters please read http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1630/what-is-too-localized

Comment: @JoeStrazzere all right thanks, I was clarifying my permanence review has nothing to do with grades or anything like that

Comment: This is a problem faced by many interns nearing the end of their internship.  It is not to localized

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Please take it to [chat].  Comments are for improving the question not answers or bullying the OP

Comment: Many interns will have a similar discussion at the end of their internship. Many of these interns will not have any experience in workplace politics, workplace evaluations, or a feedback process other than grades. This question is applicable to many of them, voting to reopen.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Closed is intended to provide a time where the question can be revised so that it meets the site requirements.  That a question is closed does not mean that it is ok to chat in comments even if it will not be reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Do not burn the bridge.**

You may think you hate working there now.  You do not know what will happen in 2, 5, 10 years and you may decide that the factors that made you hate working there as an intern are exactly the type environment that you prefer to work in as a mature and established professional.

It may also happen, that what was a decent review before you told them you did not like them,  could turn the cold and damning review after.  Smile take all their feedback as constructive criticism and thank them for the time they took to help you learn.  Find nice things to say about the company and tell them you have enjoyed your time there.

If the company says they want to make an offer tell them you would be happy to entertain an offer.  If you have another offer already it is easy to politely decline the offer, and move on.  You might find that the new offer is enticing and that the company is much easier to tolerate when making regular pay with benefits that it was at the cut rate intern pay.  Or you can find something else knowing that at least one company is willing to hire you on.  A polite decline does not burn the bridge and makes the transaction end on a high note that you can look back on positively.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is your first evaluation in the real world, you should go into the evaluation with open ears, and a closed mouth.

The evaluation is the company evaluating you, not you evaluating the company. Companies don't care why their employees or interns leave because they can always get more. Unless you are the CEO or another executive, an employee's opinion is just a bean in a hill of beans.

Your 'evaluation' won't improve if you tell your evaluator that you'd do better if the company didn't suck all of the motivation out of your body. A company isn't there to motivate you or make you happy. It is there to make money. Companies talk about motivation, and all that other happy days and rainbows stuff, but that isn't why they exist.

Comment: So even mentioning how it de-motivates me how people often talk about what a bad company this is to work for would be a bad idea?

Comment: `Companies don't care why their employees or interns leave because they can always get more` <--- I think you mean `Bad companies don't care`

Comment: @Jslam - It would be a bad idea for you to bring it up. The other employees are confiding their opinions to you. You don't want to create problems for those people.

Comment: @enderland - Ok, it would be more accurate to say that a lot of companies don't care. Whether the company is good or bad is subjective.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have your own review of the work you've done and examples to back up whatever points you want to make about your work.  For example, how did you handle conflict in the workplace?  How did you handle work-life balance?  How did you manage whatever quality of work you did do?  Be prepared with examples of whatever you think you may claim in terms of, "I've done good work," that the boss may ask, "Where was that?"

Second, be prepared to both give and receive feedback on your work.  You may be asked, "What was the hardest part of the job?" or "What advice would you have for someone that was taking an internship here?" that are rather standard questions that may come.  At the same time, you may be asked, "What was the best part of working with me?" or "What was the hardest part of working with me?" from the boss that may be part of his review.

In terms of mindsets, be prepared for both asking and answering questions.  There may be more than a few moments where you didn't know the whole story on something that may be explained in the review.  There is also the chance that it is mostly paperwork that has to do be done and thus isn't likely to get the attention that it may get in some organizations.

If you state something like, "I do not think this job is a good fit for me," that may well merit a "Why?" reply that you then have to articulate why it isn't a good fit.  Is there another department that may be a better fit?  Is there a different kind of work within the department that may work better?  If you say, "No," too much you may appear fussy which I doubt is the intention you want to be giving here.